# In SharePoint 2013 is there a security group that allows full access to all content in a farm by default?

Tags: 2013, security

I'm setting up a SharePoint 2013 development server and I've added my account to the Farm Admin group.

In prior versions this meant that I had access to all content in the farm by default. It looks like this is no longer the case. It looks like I can explicitly add myself to site collection admin groups when needed just not all by default.

**Questions**
Is this a new and by design from Microsoft?
If not, is there a security group that allows full access to all content in a farm by default?